# Split plug gfci replacement

Tags: wiring, repair, gfci

In my kitchen I have 2 countertop plugs, each is on its own circuit wired with 12/3 and top and bottom receptacles are split. Red going to top black to bottom and shared neutral. How would I replace them with GFCI's?

Comment: You have circuit breakers, not fuses, right?

Comment: Also, do you want to retain the split receptacles, or are you OK with one receptacle being on one side of the circuit and the other receptacle being on the other side?

Comment: Yes I have breakers and was hoping to maintain the split receptacles without spending the kind of money they want for a GFCI breaker.

Comment: You're stuck then -- GFCI receptacles can't be split, and it's probably cheaper to use the GFCI breaker than it is to fuss around with deadfront GFCIs, multi-gang boxes, and 12/2/2 wire.

Comment: What type of breakers does your panel take btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the only way to accomplish what you're asking is to use a double pole 20A GFCI breaker, as there is no such thing as multi-wire branch circuit GFCI receptacle.

Preferably, if it existed, you'd use a double pole 20A DFCI "Dual GFCI + AFCI" breaker, but until then your only option is the GFCI double pole.

Credit goes to SpeedyPetey for helping make this a good answer.

Comment: Replacement breakers are not required to be AFCI. Only modifications to the branch circuit wiring do. Simply replacing receptacles with GFI does not modify the branch circuit wiring.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey ahh that I totally forgot.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is true current code requires AFCI/ GFCI , but you are not required to use AFCI's if you want to update to GFCI's. There are 2 ways to accomplish the upgrade to GFCI' s the first is install a 2 pole GFCI breaker in your panel this would require going to the panel to reset a fault. The 2nd would be use 2 GFCI outlets the first 2 outlets would not be split. feed all the blacks from the load side of the first outlet and put the read wire on the line side then at the next outlet feed the red into the line side of the GFCI and the remaining red outlets on the load side. Wire nut the blacks in the second box and all the remaining blacks are now protected from the first GFCI.